# how to get my password validator to work?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a password validator code that I got online and I tweaked it to fit my needs, The only thing is that am having a bit of problems with it.

my html code:

```
<form id="fleft">
<input type="password" name="Password" id="box1" /><span id="msg_out1"></span>

</form>
```

my jquery code:

```
  jQuery('#box1').keyup(function(){
    jQuery('#msg_out1').html(checkStrength(jQuery('#box1').val()))
}) 

function checkStrength(Password){

var strength = 0

if (Password.length < 6) {
    jQuery('#msg_out1').removeClass()
    jQuery('#msg_out1').addClass('notenough')
    jQuery('#msg_out1').html('&#10008; at least 6 characters.');

  }

if (Password.length > 7) strength += 1

if (Password.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/))  strength += 1

if (Password.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && Password.match(/([0-9])/))  strength += 1

if (Password.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/))  strength += 1

if (Password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~].*[!,",%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength   += 1

if (strength <= 2 ) {
    jQuery('#msg_out1').removeClass()
    jQuery('#msg_out1').addClass('notsecure')
     jQuery( "#msg_out1" ).html('&#10004; Password not secure!');
} else if (strength == 2 ) {
    jQuery('#msg_out1').removeClass()
    jQuery('#msg_out1').addClass('moresecure')
    jQuery( "#msg_out1" ).html('&#10004; Password is good, could be more secure!');
} else {
    jQuery('#msg_out1').removeClass()
    jQuery('#msg_out1').addClass('secure')
    jQuery( "#msg_out1" ).html('&#10004; Password is secure!');
}
```

}

my css:

```
  #fleft.notenough{
   color:red;
font-size:15px;
margin-left:40px;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

#fleft.notsecure{
color:rgb(255, 109, 36);
font-size:15px;
margin-left:40px;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

 #fleft.moresecure{
color:#F6FF00;
font-size:15px;
margin-left:40px;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#fleft.secure{
color:green;
font-size:15px;
margin-left:40px;
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
```

I understand how the code works, the thing is when a user enters 1 char the #msg_out1 shows password not secure which is wrong, it should be "at least 6 characters" shown, also none of the class i specified is showing. I am asking for a professional to look at this and tell me where I went wrong please.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing nothing to stop the checks after the length check fails. The first error message is set, then the code continues and finds other errors, overwriting the message each time.

You want to return after finding a problem, e.g.

```
if (Password.length < 6) {
  jQuery('#msg_out1').
    removeClass().
    addClass('notenough').
    html('&#10008; at least 6 characters.');

  return;
}
```

Comment: this worked but none of my class was applied. Should i return the name of the class?

Comment: No - missed that part. Your CSS is faulty. You need a space between the container id and the class selector, as in `#fleft .notenough{}` instead of `#fleft.notenough{}`. As it is, your CSS would only apply if that class was added to the entire container.

Answer (score 1):

mmm The problem is a tweak

Read the comments I have added in the code below

```
if (Password.length < 6) {
    jQuery('#msg_out1').removeClass()
    jQuery('#msg_out1').addClass('notenough')
    jQuery('#msg_out1').html('&#10008; at least 6 characters.');

  } 


// *** you are replacing the #msg_out1 id with '&#10008; at least 6 characters.';***

if (Password.length > 7) strength += 1

if (Password.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/))  strength += 1

if (Password.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && Password.match(/([0-9])/))  strength += 1

if (Password.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/))  strength += 1

if (Password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~].*[!,",%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength   += 1

if (strength <= 2 ) {
    jQuery('#msg_out1').removeClass()
    jQuery('#msg_out1').addClass('notsecure')
     jQuery( "#msg_out1" ).html('&#10004; Password not secure!'); 

// *** you are overriding the previous #msg_out1 id '&#10008; at least 6 characters.';
//with the new message '&#10004; Password not secure!'

} else if (strength == 2 ) {
    jQuery('#msg_out1').removeClass()
    jQuery('#msg_out1').addClass('moresecure')
    jQuery( "#msg_out1" ).html('&#10004; Password is good, could be more secure!');
} else {
    jQuery('#msg_out1').removeClass()
    jQuery('#msg_out1').addClass('secure')
    jQuery( "#msg_out1" ).html('&#10004; Password is secure!');
}
```

**Solution:**

What you can do is either:

```
if (Password.length < 6) {
        jQuery('#msg_out1').removeClass()
        jQuery('#msg_out1').addClass('notenough')
        jQuery('#msg_out1').html('&#10008; at least 6 characters.');
    return ;
      }
```

or append() method instead of html() if you want the app to be showing the both messages together

```
if (strength <= 2 ) {
    jQuery('#msg_out1').removeClass()
    jQuery('#msg_out1').addClass('notsecure')
     jQuery( "#msg_out1" ).append('&#10004; Password not secure!');
}
```

good luck

Comment: the return worked but my class is not applied, do you have a solution to this?

Comment: Why don't you just type that way                   if (Password.length<6) {your code}             else if (strength<=2) { your code}

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to make my class show:

```
 if (Password.length < 6) {
    jQuery('#msg_out4').removeClass()
    jQuery('#msg_out4').html('&#10008; at least 6 characters.').css('color','red').css('font-size','15px').css('margin-left','40px').css('font-family','"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif');
    return ;
```